# change default blue color in pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-xml

How can I change the default blue color in pre lollipop devices, for background in `ListView` or `Selector` for tab or any click selector color. I am trying to find out the property in theme, I have changed following things

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/main_background</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#689F38</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#689F38</item>
```

Comment: changing colorAccent value to desired color inside styles.xml and using that style as application's main theme should work..

Comment: no i tried the same but no change.

Comment: please post your complete styles.xml code in the question..
And Is your colorPrimary properly getting applied?